# Select distinct records with Min Date from two tables with Left Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to retrieve all distinct AccountId’s as well as the earliest InsertDate for each.  Occasionally the AccountId is not known and although the transactions may be distinct I want to bucket all of the ‘-1’s into their own group.

This is what I have attempted so far along with the schemas.

```
    CREATE TABLE #tmpResults (
        Trans Varchar(12),                              
    AccountId Varchar(50),                          
EarlyDate DateTime DEFAULT getdate(),                                                                               CardType Varchar(16))

insert #tmpResults
        select [Trans]                              = convert(varchar(12),'CashSale')
        ,   [AccountId]                             = b.AccountId
        ,   [EarlyDate]                             = min(b.InsertDate)
        ,   case when c.name LIKE '%VISA%'      then 'VISA'
                    when c.name LIKE '%MasterCard%' then 'MasterCard'
                    when c.name LIKE '%AMEX%'       then 'AMEX'
                    else 'Other'
            end as [CardType] 
        from TransBatch b
        left join CardVer_3 c WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.Id = B.BatchId
        left join TransBatch b2
        on (b.accountid = b2.accountid and (b.InsertDate > b2.InsertDate or b.InsertDate = b2.InsertDate))
        and b2.accountid is NULL
        group by b.accountid, b.InsertDate,c.name       
        order by b.accountid DESC

        select * from  #tmpResults
```

The table schemas are like so:

```
**TransBatch**  
RecordId    |BatchId    |InsertDate     | AccountId     | AccNameHolder  
6676    |   11  |   2012-11-01 05:19:04.000 |   12345   |   Account1  
6677    |   11  |   2012-11-01 05:19:04.000 |   12345   |   Account1  
6678    |   11  |   2012-11-01 05:19:04.000 |   55555   |   Account2  
6679    |   11  |   2012-11-01 05:19:04.000 |   -1  |   NULL  
6680    |   12  |   2012-11-02 05:20:04.000 |   12345   |   Account1  
6681    |   12  |   2012-11-02 05:20:04.000 |   55555   |   Account2  
6682    |   13  |   2012-11-04 06:20:04.000 |   44444   |   Account3  
6683    |   14  |   2012-11-05 05:30:04.000 |   44444   |   Account3  
6684    |   14  |   2012-11-05 05:31:04.000 |   -1  |   NULL  


**CardVer_3**  
BatchId     |Name  
11      |MasterCard  
12      |Visa  
13      |AMEX   
14      |GoCard
```

This will be an intermediate table, the output is planned to look like the attached.

[image: No of distinct accounts per cardtype grouped by min age (date from today)]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to get the full record for the minimum insert date time.  For this, you want to use windows functions:

```
select 'CashSale' as Trans,
       AccountId,
       min(InsertDate),
       (case when name LIKE '%VISA%'      then 'VISA'
             when name LIKE '%MasterCard%' then 'MasterCard'
             when name LIKE '%AMEX%'       then 'AMEX'
             else 'Other'
        end) as [CardType] 
from (select AccountId, InsertDate, c.name,
             row_number() over (partition by AccountId order by insertDate desc) as seqnum
      from TransBatch b left join
           CardVer_3 c WITH (NOLOCK)
           ON c.Id = B.BatchId
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

I'm taking a guess that "CashSale" means that the credit card did not match.  The TransId is then either the recordId or "CashSale".

Comment: Gordon, thanks for the feedback but this is returning a large number of errors:  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'Trans'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
Invalid column name 'insertDate'.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 10 etc

Comment: I should *always* convert SQL code to my standard indentation style.  Most (all?) of the problems were due to the names in the `select` statement.  I missed the way columns were being renamed.

Comment: Hi - still a few errors. I've tried replacing CashSale with Trans but no luck. I'm unsure as to how to address to other 2 messages:   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 Invalid column name 'Cashsale'. Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 9 No column was specified for column 5 of 't'. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 Invalid column name 'seqnum'.

Comment: @user1773949 . . . In your original query, I can't see what the string 'CashSale' is for.  I guessed in the edits I made . . . that you want either the RecordId for a credit card transaction or the word "CashSale".  The key in this version is not using `group by` but using `row_number` instead.

Comment: CashSale is a constant I have assigned to all transactions. I need to union this query with another similarly structured dataset that has a different value for this constant. The accountId and cardtype have a 1 to 1 relationship. What I need it to return is one record per accountId. It is currently returning one record per Accountid AND Date combination. I should only get one record for accountid 44444  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfbc3/1

Answer (score 0):

Gordon, I made some very minor changes to your suggestion and believe I have the correct output: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfbc3/7/0 . Thank you very much. I'm not at all familiar with the windows functions so I'm going to brush up on these.

The code is here:
`select 'CashSale' as [Trans],

           AccountId,

           min(InsertDateTime),

           (case when name LIKE '%VISA%'      then 'VISA'

                when name LIKE '%MasterCard%' then 'MasterCard'

                when name LIKE '%AMEX%'       then 'AMEX'

                else 'Other'

           end) as [CardType]

from (select AccountId, InsertDateTime, c.name,

             row_number() over (partition by AccountId order by insertDateTime asc) as seqnum

      from TransBatch b left join

           CardVer_3 c WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.batchId = B.BatchId

     ) t

where seqnum = 1

group by t.accountid, t.name`

The next steps are to dump this into a temp table and try and get the output looking like the attached excel screen.

Comment: Desc has been changed to Asc and I've adding the group by criteria